# xpath question for scraping the content inside a link

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I started learning scrapy and would like to know how I can get information of each school by State in an excel file. Each state is a link to another page and I'm not sure how to write the xpath syntax for this. Please advise.

https://www.raise.me/high-school

```
import scrapy
class RaisemeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'raiseme'
    allowed_domains = ['raise.me/high-school']
    start_urls = ['http://raise.me/high-school/']
    def parse(self, response):
        h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
        yield {'H1 Tag': h1_tag }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract links to different states with `response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "links-list-list-item")]/a/@href').get()`

SelectorGadget is a useful extension to extract xpath and css selectors.
Just remember to disable javascript in dev tools. The source will be different for websites loaded in scrapy shell (without javascript) and in the browser (with javascript).